# How to enable https for jetty using XmlConfiguration?

Tags: java, https, jetty, jetty-9

We have an OSGi based server, from where we use an embedded jetty to handle webtraffic.
I'm using the `XmlConfiguration` to create a jetty server instance, see the code below.
 
The `configStream` is the from the `jetty-http.xml` which is read per default from our plugin or from a custom location.

Now I'm trying to enable https for the server. I would like to load the `jetty-ssl.xml` and `jetty-https.xml` the same as `jetty-http.xml`.

How can I do that? I can't load another stream into the `XmlConfiguration`.
Is there another approach, maybe without `XmlConfiguration`?

```
XmlConfiguration xmlConfig = new XmlConfiguration(configStream);
Object root = xmlConfig.configure();
if (!(root instanceof Server)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected a Server object as a root for server configuration"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
server = (Server) root;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, see the code below.
`XmlConfiguration` can be used for all xml files, if two of them create a `Server` instance (e.g. `jetty.xml` and `jetty-ssl.xml`), only one `Server` is created and configurations/beans are added to the same instance.

```
List<String> configurations = new ArrayList<String>();
configurations.add("jetty.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$

// use pre-configured jetty xml files to construct a server instance
if (System.getProperty("jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath") != null) { //$NON-NLS-1$
    configurations.add("jetty-ssl.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    configurations.add("jetty-ssl-context.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    configurations.add("jetty-https.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
} else {
    configurations.add("jetty-http.xml"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}

XmlConfiguration last = null;
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

for (String configFile : configurations) {
    InputStream configStream = null;

    File xmlConfiguration = new File(webserverHome, CONFIG_LOCATION + configFile);
    if (xmlConfiguration.exists()) {
        configStream = new FileInputStream(xmlConfiguration);
        logger.info("Using custom XML configuration {}", xmlConfiguration); //$NON-NLS-1$
    } else {
        // configStream = ... // read from bundle
        logger.info("Using default XML configuration {}/{}", Activator.PLUGIN_ID, CONFIG_LOCATION + configFile); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }

    XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(configStream);
    if (last != null) {
        configuration.getIdMap().putAll(last.getIdMap());
    }
    objects.add(configuration.configure());
    last = configuration;
}

// first object is a Server instance because of the jetty.xml
server = (Server) objects.get(0);
```